# Why changing object itself through class object doesn't work?

Tags: python-3.x, object, class-method

```
class Cat:
    def func(self):
        self = None

a = Cat()

print(a)

a.func()

print(a)
```

I thought I would get None with second print function, but I got same object addresses for both prints. Why can't I modify object with class method?

Comment: You aren't changing the object itself. You are simply assigning `None` to the local variable `self`. There's nothing magical about `self`, it doesn't even have to be *called* `self`. It's just a regular variable, that automatically get's passed the instance. Assignment to a variable never mutates an object, and in any case, you can't "transform" an object into `None` (without some serious hacking of the runtime internals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class method, `self` is an argument that becomes part of the local scope. Assigning to any local scope variable only changes the local scope. If you were to assign to an attribute of `self` such as

```
self.foo = “Bar”
```

Then you would modify the object itself.

Furthermore, the object is referenced by `a` in the calling (global) scope and that reference would prevent destruction of the object.

Put another way, `self` and `a` both refer to the same object and assigning `self=None` only removes one of those references.

Comment: So if you want to change object itself to another one with class method, it’s not possible. But if I insist, I just have to change each properties one by one?

Comment: It’s not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you provide more details of your ultimate goal?

Comment: Actually my original goal was from BST Class. I was trying to assign child node to its parent node by just overwriting child node on parent node. But as it turned out on Cat class that I posted, I couldn’t do it. So solution for my goal is to change each properties in parent node to what is in child node? (If this didn’t help, I’ll just post whole code for you)

Comment: You could just overwrite the parent's properties from the child if there is nothing else that cares about parent in its current form, though I'm not sure if that is the *best* way to go. But it does save you from having to keep track of the thing that refers to the parent.

Comment: What I wanted to do is just erase parent node so I think that will do, but I agree with if its the best way to do it. That’s why I posted this question in the first place.^^